# git svn fetch -- Checksum mismatch | git svn log -- fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'

Tags: git, svn

I initialized a new git repository with a url that pointed to an existing svn repo.

```
$ git init http://xxxxx/svn
```

I then executed 'git svn fetch'.

```
$ git svn fetch
```

This was working great (revisions were being imported one by one) until i got an error.  I had to stop and start the fetch process several times because there are a large number of revisions in the svn repo.  I recently got the following error and i am not able to continue.

```
$ git svn fetch
Checksum mismatch: xxx/yyy/zzz.java 091f277343646871f019a159af895ed5943ce0fc
expected: 5fad939c76344afa9fa088fa843aba5e
     got: 8bc1f834ffce935fa67cc5cde94a9e14
```

Now every time i try to execute 'git svn fetch', i get the error above.

I have tried to get the last revision of the file but that fails as well.

```
$ git svn log xxx/yyy/zzz.java
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
rev-list --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD --: command returned error: 128
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$ git svn reset -r##### -p
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
rev-list --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD --: command returned error: 128
```

What can i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have got the same issue.

Comment: @notionquest No,  I was not able to solve the problem.  I had to restart.  But, in my second attempt, I provided the starting and ending revisions in my git svn command in order to limit the number of revisions checked out. Ex (something like this): git svn clone [url] -rSTART_REV:HEAD.